# Visual Basic add row to datatable which has values from database

Tags: .net, vb.net

Am trying to add a row to datagriview which has records from database but when i do so, the existing data from database disappear and show new records (row). What could be the problem? Help please
CODE SNIPPET

```
Dim dt as new DataTable
Dim R As DataRow = dt.NewRow
R("ProductName") = txtProductName.Text
dt.Rows.Add(R)
DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

Comment: You need to use  the DataSource property of the DataGrid as your table where you add the new row. But you really should use a BindingSource if you want to update the grid from external code

Answer (score 0):

You can use .Merge() as long as both datatable has the same columns.

```
Dim dt as new DataTable
Dim dtOldData as new DataTable
Dim R As DataRow = dt.NewRow
R("ProductName") = txtProductName.Text

dtOldData = DataGridView1.DataSource

dt.Rows.Add(R)
dtOldData.Merge(dt)

DataGridView1.DataSource = dtOldData
```

Comment: This seems to work but i have an error "DataType property mismatch". The reason of this error is that one column is text and the other is decimal. I have tried to convert the txtprice.tex to decimal as such but its not working.
TRIED
 R("unit_price") = Convert.ToDecimal(txtUnitPrice.Text)

Comment: Solved i have used this dt2.Merge(dt, True, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore) thanks you guys